Why am I unable to locate the xpath with selenium?
https://www.auronia.de/trauring-konfigurator
How do I click the accept button of the cookies field? Somehow I can't locate the xpath with the open website.
I got this xpath: '//[@id="focus-lock-id"]/div/div/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/div/div/button[2]'
and I constantly get this error message:
An error occurred: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//[@id="focus-lock-id"]/div/div/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/div/div/button[2]"}
And the respective part of the code looks like here:
try:
            if config.get("cookies_button") and cookies == 1:
                # cookies button if necessary to click
                time.sleep(10)
                print("looking for cookies button")
                button_cookies = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, config["cookies_button"])
                print("clicking cookies")
                WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,                     button_cookies))).click()
                print("clicked the cookies button")
                cookies = 0
                time.sleep(2)  # Adjust as needed for the modal dialog to appear


"cookies_button" refers to the xpath shown above, and as you can see from the error message, it's the same xpath.
But why doesn't it work? I don't see any iframes. Not sure what I am doing wrong here?

you have to rewrite your question and organize the code because no one can use your code like this, it is not a complete snippet, and use stackoverflow tools to write code and you can put the xpath in a container, to be more clear.

The problem is that the element you are looking for is in a shadow-root,
<div id="usercentrics-root" data-created-at="1714251385660" style="">
  #shadow-root (open)

It behaves similar to an IFRAME. You have to switch Selenium's context into that shadow-root before looking for the element. A code sample is below.
shadow_host = driver.find_element(By.ID, "usercentrics-root")
shadow_root = shadow_host.shadow_root
shadow_content = shadow_root.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "button[@data-testid='uc-accept-all-button']")


Ohhh, I see. I didn't see the shadow root. I have however encountered this in the past. I will test this in a few minutes (having a break now)
Thank you so much.
